# Defining Capistrano 3 Task specific log_level

Tags: capistrano3

By default, my capistrano 3 settings is: `set :log_level, :info`
It helps to remove noise while deploying.

But I would like to change that value for specific task, for example `tail log_file`
Otherwise, no output is displayed.

```
desc "tail rails logs"
task :tail do
  on roles(:app) do
    execute "tail -f #{shared_path}/log/#{fetch(:rails_env)}.log"
  end
end
```

What is the correct way to change log_level settings for specific rake task?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

While checking the capistrano Source Code, I noticed that configure_backend is called before task invoke. Thus, my settings change was ignored. I fixed it as following:

```
def set_output
  set :log_level, :debug
  configure_backend
end

desc "tail rails logs"
task :tail do
  set_output
  on roles(:app) do
    execute "tail -f #{shared_path}/log/#{fetch(:rails_env)}.log"
  end
end
```